# Update all records using a function sql

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I am looking to update a calculated sum in sql

Basically I have a table:

```
ImportID  SeiralNumber   Day   Hour     value    Difference   Complete
1             123         1     1         6         NULL        0
2             123         1     2         8         NULL        0
3             123         1     5         21        NULL        0
4             123         1     6         28        NULL        0
5             222         2     2         12        NULL        0
6             222         2     5         18        NULL        0
7             222         2     4         16        NULL        0
8             222         1     12        8         NULL        0
```

For each serial number there will be a day 1-365 and hour through 1-12, all I want to do is calculate the difference filed from the record before

So take ImportID 6, I need to get the record which is on the same day and the hour before (importID 7) then I need to update the Difference using the value field which is 18 -17 = 1.

N.B. There may be gaps in the sequence and if there is no previous record then the difference should stay as `NULL`. Once they have been calculated they need to be inserted into a new table only when the difference is now `not null` and it doesn't exist in the table already, on a successful insert they get marked as **complete**. Also a record before can be a previous day (day 1 hour 12) is the record before (day 2, hour 1)

Currently I am using a loop to select the null values, get the previous record, update the record, if its OK insert  into other table, update the Completed field.

My issue is that this is working on a million records and it is taking a long while to Select the applicable records (completed = 0) into a temp table and loop through each.

Is there any quicker way to mass process these as an update statement? Or separate statements?

The result should be

```
ImportID  SeiralNumber   Day   Hour     value    Difference   Complete
1             123         1     1         6         NULL        0
2             123         1     2         8         2           1
3             123         1     5         21        NULL        0
4             123         1     6         28        7           1
5             222         2     1         12        4           1
6             222         2     5         18        2           1
7             222         2     4         16        NULL        0
8             222         1     12        8         NULL        0
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: SQL Server 2008 r2 and management studio

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this is basically it isn't it?

```
DECLARE @TABLE TABLE
(
    ImportId INT,
    SerialNumber INT,
    Day INT,
    Hour INT,
    Value INT,
    Difference INT,
    Complete INT
)

INSERT INTO @TABLE VALUES
(1,123,1,1,6,NULL,0),
(2,123,1,2,8,NULL,0),
(3,123,1,5,21,NULL,0),
(4,123,1,6,28,NULL,0),
(5,222,2,1,12,NULL,0),
(6,222,2,5,18,NULL,0),
(7,222,2,4,16,NULL,0),
(8,222,1,12,8,NULL,0)

SELECT * FROM @Table

UPDATE T
    SET T.Difference = T.Value - TT.Value,
    Complete = 1
FROM
(
    SELECT *
    ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY SerialNumber ORDER BY Day ASC, Hour ASC) AS RowCounter
    FROM @TABLE
    WHERE Complete = 0 --Ignore completed ones  
)AS T
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT *
    ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY SerialNumber ORDER BY Day ASC, Hour ASC) AS RowCounter
    FROM @TABLE
)AS TT
ON T.SerialNumber = TT.SerialNumber
WHERE
(
    T.RowCounter = TT.RowCounter + 1
    AND
    T.Day = TT.Day 
    AND
    T.Hour = TT.Hour + 1
)
OR
(
    T.Day = TT.Day + 1 
    AND
    T.Hour = 1
    AND
    TT.Hour = 12
)

SELECT * FROM @TABLE
```

Comment: Perfect! Thanks for this, It definately resolves the update. I will add the inserts next and I will test the time differences but I imagine it will be far quicker.

Comment: @CR41G14 If you want you can filter the "AS T" bit to do rows maybe a few thousand or so at a time - If you're doing millions at a time remember you might fill up your transaction log or hammer the server :) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2082751 could be relevant