# Join between two tables with business logic on billion rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, join, sql-update

I have source and table destination tables like this

```
Source:

    Column1 Column2 Column3 Column4

Destination:

    Column1 Column2 Column5 Column6
```

How can I implement this logic in SQL SERVER

```
IF SOURCE.Column1 = DESTINATION.Column1 AND SOURCE.Column2 = DESTINATION.Column2
UPDATE DESTINATION Column5 = SOURCE.Column1 + 12 (some other logic)
ELSE
Do something else
```

The issue is, that I have to deal with billion rows, so what is the best way to implement the above logic

**EDIT1**

```
IF SOURCE.Column1 = DESTINATION.Column1 AND SOURCE.Column2 = DESTINATION.Column2
UPDATE DESTINATION Column5 = SOURCE.Column1 + 12 (some other logic)
ELSE
**INSERT SOURCE table row to the destination**
```

How can I implement the same with merge statement, because I have to consider only two columns

Comment: Just to add to your headache, if you are updating billions of rows, the other issue you need to consider is availability. Can you afford to take the database off (single user) for you to execute the change? Noting that when you run a mass update like this, impact on your application response time will be significant and could take hours.
If you can take the database offline, great; if not, then you need to figure out some kind of "batching".

Comment: @JosephLess Thanks for the suggestion and it is worth considering. But as all the OLAP cubes and reports are linked to the database I can not take the database down.

Comment: @Zerotoinfinite if there's a billion rows OR you can't have downtime - Look into nibbling updates (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2082751 is an example). With a billion row single update your transaction log will go crazy, also the locking will hurt all other users.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<strike>You can `UPDATE` with `JOIN` and that would be more performance wise in your case. Like so:</strike>

```
UPDATE d
SET d.Column5 = CASE WHEN some logic THEN s.Column1 + 12 (some other logic)
                     ELSE Something else
                ELSE
FROM DESTINATION d
LEFT JOIN SOURCE s ON s.Column2 = d.Colcumn2;
```

---

You can use the [**`MERGE`**](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510625.aspx) statement like so:

```
MERGE INTO SOURCE AS TGT
USING DESTINATION AS SRC
  ON TGT.Column1 = SRC.Column1 
WHEN MATCHED THEN
  UPDATE SET
    TGT.Column5 = SRC.Column1 + 12 (some other logic)
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
  INSERT (Source columns list)
  VALUES (...);
```

**Note that:**

- In the `INSERT` statement there was no `INTO TableName`, because the name of the target table is already defined in the `MERGE` clause, which is `SOURCE`. Thats why I defined `SOURCE AS TGT` and `DESTINATION AS SRC`.
- It is mandatory to end the `MERGE` statement with semicolon. And it is best practice to do so with al sql statements.

Comment: You can include the `ELSE` part using `CASE` expression. See my edit.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I am working on that but I have a problem that I am now mentioning in my edit part of the question.

Comment: I have written this but I am getting error 

MERGE DESTINATIONTable AS DST
USING  SourceTable AS SRC
ON  DST.Column1 = SRC.Column1  AND DST.Column2 = SRC.Column2
WHEN MATCHED THEN
    SELECT 1
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
    SELECT 2

Comment: @Zerotoinfinite There is no `SELECT` clause in the query I posted. Please can you show me the exact query you used.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/22448/discussion-between-zerotoinfinite-and-mahmoud-gamal)

Comment: You are correct. There are some contraints in using merge which you have mentioned in your answer. :) Thanks for your immense help.

Comment: @Zerotoinfinite Sorry, I can't chat right now. I am on work. Sorry for that. Give some minutes please. Can you please setup a demo explaining the issue [**in this site**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/) please? thanks.

Comment: Just one last question, is it necessary to keep Destination table with using and Source table as merge ??

Comment: @Zerotoinfinite What do you mean? IF I understand correclty, you can do a `SELECT` clause inside the `USING` block something like `USING ( put your query here) AS foo ...`.